# PDF to bitmap image conversoin using mupdf in arm

Tags: pdf, bitmap, mupdf

How can I use the mupdf API to convert pdf to bitmap in arm platform with the C language?

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858689/using-mupdf-with-curl-flip-effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mudraw sample code already does this, can't you either just use it as is, or look at that for clues ?

Comment: thanks!The example.c can convert pdf to png,but i want convert pgm.so i search the bitmap.h found mupdf can convert pdf to pbm,and i want add a new FUNC convert pdf to pgm ,did i'm right?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not an expert, but broadly speaking if you want a new file format you will have to add something like that yes. You might try going to the #ghostscript channel on irc.freenode.net and asking there, the MuPDF developers will often answer questions there (but be prepared to wait a bit, just ask your question and hang around, or check back later, the channel is logged)